# What's the best, REST-ful way to restrict access to subset of resource?

Tags: rest, web-services, api-design

Let's say I have a rest service with 3 different resources: `/libraries`, `/books` and `/users`. Users belong to libraries, and books belong to libraries. Users should not be able to see books from libraries they don't belong to. After authenticating, every request to the service includes a token with the user id.

What should my request look like if I want to get all of the books I have access to?

1) `GET /books`

- (Api endpoint scopes by the user in the auth endpoint)

2) `GET /users/:id/libraries` => `GET /library/:id/books`

- Use my user id
- Do a separate request for each library the user belongs to
- Return a `401` when the user calls `GET /books`

3) `GET /users/current/libraries` => `GET /library/:id/books`

- Do not use my user id
- Do a separate request for each library the user belongs to
- Return a `401` when the user calls `GET /books`

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about this alternative?

```
GET /users/{id}/libraries/all/books
```

It would deliver all books (`/books`) for all libraries (`/libraries/all`) of a specific user (`/users/{id}`) which is more or less exactly what your requirement is.

Some people prefer to shortcut the specific resource identification `all` (or similar) in which case the call would look like this (goes off the REST guideline):

```
GET /users/{id}/libraries/books
```

Regarding the 401 (or possibly a 403) situation: if the `{id}` is the one related to your authorization token, you just deliver the requested information. If the ID is different, you deliver a 401 (or possibly a 403), while a call like `GET /users/{id}/libraries` would still result in a normal 200 OK response unless you also disallow querying the library information.

Comment: Have you seen anyone use option 1 successfully?

Comment: I haven't and with all respect, there's a lot of indirection going on which is hard to follow. An API that requires functional documentation is hard to consume and will cause more development and maintenance effort than a clear API. `GET /books` should get you all books, not books that are provided by the libraries to which you have access depending on whether you are authenticated or not. It's RESTful but implicit hence creates unnecessary complexities. The more you think of resources and sub-resources, the more you align yourself with REST and you make it easy to follow for you and others.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. Do a lot of people share your opinion on that?

I can see benefits to each way of doing things and am looking for the canonical way to handle this particular problem (assuming there is one). Based on your reply and some discussion that I've had with other people, either what you proposed or option 2 seems like the way to go in most cases.

Comment: It's not an opinion I have. It's reading the RESTful guideline and applying it to your requirement (having no other context than your question). Option 2 is equally fine, but is typically less ideal due to multiple requests are required for a consumer to just retrieve the data plus having to aggregate it. Also, depending on the infrastructure and the number of consumers it can cause a performance problem. And yes, I have seen that problem often with lots of time and money lost due to non-functional requirements being neglected.